# marionette region undefined following init

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

The error ONLY occurs under a special routing circumstance when the layout (see gist link) is called by the router following a login processed in a different controller and routed here by the global event mechanism.

Everything is fine as long as an existing session is reused and there is NO Logon processed.

main code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rowntreerob/8809779) ( error at line #113 "this.headerRegion" not defined

Code blocks coming to the gist module , from logon and from router...

```
        loginSuccess: function (user) {
            vent.trigger('user:login'); //notify all widgets we have logged in
            app.router.navigate('home', { trigger: true });
        }
...

    return marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        routes: {
            'home' : 'home',
...
        },

        home: function() {
            this._showPage('home');
        },

...
        _showPage: function (pageName, options) {
            console.log("RouterShow " +pageName);
            var that = this;
            //make sure we are authenicated, if not go to login
            if (!Parse.User.current())
                pageName = 'login';

            require(['./pages/' + pageName + '/Controller'], function (PageController) {
                if (that.currentPageController) {
                    that.currentPageController.close();
                    that.currentPageController = null;
                }
// line below loads the layout in the gist link
                that.currentPageController = new PageController(options);

                that.currentPageController.show(app.regionMain)
                    .fail(function () {
                        //display the not found page
                        that.navigate('/not-found', { trigger: true, replace: true });
                    });

            });
        }
...

define([
    'marionette',
    './Layout',
    'app'
], function (
    Marionette,
    Layout,
    app
) {
    'use strict';

    return Marionette.Controller.extend({
        show: function (region) {
            var that = this, d = new Marionette.$.Deferred();
            region.show(new Layout({ }));  //this layout in gist link
            return d.promise();
        }
    });
});
```

`pageController.show()` near the end of the above block calls the Layout region in the gist

To recreate the error that ONLY OCCURs following a logon, I do the following:

Show compoundView #1 at line #57 of the gist.

click in compound view #1 firing event at line #40 of the gist ('**roleList:getuser**',)

swap new views #2  into EXISTING regions used for the first views at lines #113, 114

ERROR at 113, "this.headerRegion" no longer exists in the layout!

Discussion - now IMO Layout extends Marionett.ItemView and from the source, it should always have the regions defined before calling init. The constructor checks for undef "this.headerRegion" at line #23 of the gist.

My code reimplements the superclass constructor in lines 18 - 23 of the gist and it looks like "headerRegion" and "mainRegion" attributes are always defined. But, the error is :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined
>   Layout.js:113 Marionette.Layout.extend.getUserRelation

Answer (score 1):

The region properties like 'headerRegion' in your case are only available after render(), not just initialize(). From the Marionette [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md):

> Once you've rendered the layout, you now have direct access to all of
>   the specified regions as region managers.

You must be triggering those events ('roleItem:getrole', etc.) before the layout is rendered in logic outside the gist. Instead you'll need to render first if you want to implement getUserRelation() in this way.